# How to copy only non-duplicate files whilst maintaining folder structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I am trying to find duplicates between two folders and copy only unique image files to the 'dest' folder. I can copy all the non-dupes using the code below, however it doesn't maintain the source directory structure. I think OS.walk returns 3 tuples, but they aren't linked so not sure how to re-construct the sub dir?

Example:

```
import shutil, os
from difPy import dif
source = input('Input source folder:')
dest = input('Input backup \ destination folder:')

ext = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.JPG','.JPEG','.GIF')

search = dif(source, dest)
result = search.result
result


dupes = []
srcfiles = []
filecount = []
failed = []
removed = []

for i in result.values(): 
        dupes.append(i['location'])

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(ext):
            srcfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))

for f in srcfiles:
                if f not in dupes:
                        shutil.copy(f, dest)
                        print('File copied successfully - '+f)
                        filecount.append(f)
                else:
                        print('File not copied successfully !!!! - '+f)
                        failed.append(f)
```

I have also tried using the shutil.copytree function with an ignore list, however it requires a new folder and can't get the ignore list function to work

shutil.copytree example:

```
for i in result.values(): 
        df = []
        df.append(i['filename'])

def ignorelist(source, df):
        return [f for f in df if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, f))]

shutil.copytree(source, destnew, ignore=ignorelist)
```

Comment: https://github.com/gchamon/sysrsync might give you what you are after for minimum effort.

Comment: Do you have any examples of unique and duplicate files in the source folder? e.g. Folder_A contains: pic1.png, pic2.png, pic9.png; Folder_B contians: pic2.png, picY.png, picW4K.png. The way I am interpreting your question is that you would wish for Folder_NEW to have pic1.png, pic2.png, pic9.png, picY.png, picW4K.png. Does that sound right?

Comment: @kyrlon, Ideally, Folder_B would then have pic1.png, pic2.png, pic9.png, picY.png, picW4K.png without creating a new folder. However the problem I can't yet solve is when Folder_A has a subfolder e.g. Folder_A\subfolder\pic.png, it is just copied into Folder_B without re-creating that subfolder (with the 1st example code).

Comment: with the shutil.copytree method, it needs to create a new folder, so Folder_B would contain Folder_B\New and pic1.png, pic9.png as non dupes. But again, if there's a subfolder under Folder_A, it's not maintained when copied.

Comment: @W4K1NG You just need to tell the shutil.copy the right destination and make sure the directory exists before calling shutil.copy - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function ignorelist should do the trick:

```
import shutil, os
from difPy import dif
source = input('Input source folder:')
dest = input('Input backup \ destination folder:')

ext = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif')

search = dif(source, dest)

dupes = [value['location'] for value in search.result.values()]

def ignorelist(source, files):
    return [file for file in files
                    if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, file))
                         and (os.path.join(source, file) in dupes
                              or not file.lower().endswith(ext)))]

shutil.copytree(source, dest, ignore=ignorelist)
```

And the other "more manual" way would be

```
import shutil, os
from difPy import dif
source = input('Input source folder:').rstrip('/\\')
dest = input('Input backup \ destination folder:').rstrip('/\\')

ext = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif')

search = dif(source, dest)

dupes = [value['location'] for value in search.result.values()]

srcfiles = []
copied = []
failed = []
skipped = []

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith(ext):
            srcfile = os.path.join(dirpath,file)
            srcfiles.append(srcfile)
            if srcfile in dupes:
                print('File not copied (duplicate) - '+srcfile)
                skipped.append(srcfile)
            else:
                try:
                    destfile = os.path.join(dest,srcfile[len(source)+1:])
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destfile), exist_ok=True)
                    shutil.copy(srcfile,destfile)
                    print('File copied successfully - '+srcfile)
                    copied.append(srcfile)
                except Exception as err:
                    print('File not copied (error %s) - %s' % (str(err),srcfile))
                    failed.append(f)
```

Comment: A couple of comments: Your doing this by calling `copytree` with an exception list overlooks the possibility that the source directory contains files other than images, which will not be in the exception list and will erroneously get copied. Your *manual* implementation does not have this problem. Also, your definition of `dupes` does not use a *list comprehension*. which would be faster. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/8G12Qm).

Comment: @Booboo Okay... I updated the answer to use list comprehension for dupes and in the return statement of function ignorelist but I don't understand the first part of your comment. The function ignorelist will put any file not ending in .jpg, .jpeg or .gif on the list of files to be ignored. Therefore no unwanted files should be copied by copytree.

Comment: You are correct; I missed `or not file.lower().endswith(ext)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed some variable names to make them more descriptive. And what you call `failed` is really just a list of files that are not copied because they are duplicates rather than files whose copying was attempted but failed.

```py
import shutil, os
from difPy import dif

source = input('Input source folder: ')
dest = input('Input backup \ destination folder: ')

# Remove trailing path separators if they exist:
if source.endswith(('/', '\\')):
    source = source[:-1]
if dest.endswith(('/', '\\')):
    dest = dest[:-1]

# Use the correct path separator to
# ensure correct matching with dif results:
if os.sep == '/':
    source = source.replace('\\', os.sep)
elif os.sep == '\\':
    source = source.replace('/', os.sep)

source_directory_length = len(source) + 1

ext = ('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.JPG','.JPEG','.GIF')

search = dif(source, dest)
result = search.result

# Set comprehension:
dupes = {duplicate['location'] for duplicate in result.values()}

copied = []
not_copied = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            source_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            if source_path not in dupes:
                # get subdirectory of source directory that this file is in:
                file_length = len(file) + 1
                # Get subdirectory relative to the source directory:
                subdirectory = source_path[source_directory_length:-file_length]
                if subdirectory:
                    dest_directory = os.path.join(dest, subdirectory)
                    # ensure directory exists:
                    os.makedirs(dest_directory, exist_ok=True)
                else:
                    dest_directory = dest
                dest_path = os.path.join(dest_directory, file)
                shutil.copy(source_path, dest_path)
                print('File copied successfully -', source_path)
                copied.append(source_path)
            else:
                print('File not copied -', source_path)
                not_copied.append(source_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, can fail for other reasons too though.

Comment: Yes, a copy might fail. But your code was *not* testing for an unsuccessful copy. You were only putting into `failed` those items for which no attempt at copying was made because they were duplicates, not because the copying failed as was suggested by the message you print. And nothing stops you from modifying this code to also test for an unsuccessful copy and putting those files into an additional list named `failed`. So you would have 3 lists, those successfully copied, those not copied because they were duplicates and those whose copy failed.